# Critério para enviar e-mail - modulo de subtração google-appscript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

O objetivo do trecho de cógido a seguir é pegar uma data que está na coluna 5 subtraí-la da data de hoje e, se o módulo dessa divisão for igual a zero, é enviado um email. No caso, eu quero que seja enviado um email a cada três meses enquanto o `if` principal contiver, na coluna `tipoAlerta` a `string` `Trimestral` e na coluna `monitoramento` a `string` `Em andamento`. Eu sei que o problema está no trecho `dataRange[i][5]-dataHoje)%90==0`, porque, uma vez que eu removo, o código funciona. A lógica está certa, o `new Date()` também retorna a data atual. Então, não sei onde posso está errando, pois o email não é enviado. Embora, não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro.

```
 for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){
        var monitoramento = dataRange[i][10]
        var tipoAlerta = dataRange[i][15]
        //var dataHoje = new Date(); --- Varivel anterior que deu //problemas
        var dataHoje = dataRange[i][17] //Nova variavel. OK. 

          if (tipoAlerta == 'Trimestral' && monitoramento=='Em Andamento') { 
              if ((dataRange[i][5]-dataHoje)%90==0) {
                MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: emailAddress.toString(),
                subject: subject,
                htmlBody: message
              }); 
            } 
}
```

Comment: Antes do segundo if, faz um `console.log((dataRange[i][5]-dataHoje)%90)` e veja o que mostra.

Comment: Não está permitindo. Tanto o console.log quanto o Logger.log(), dá a mensagem Falta ; antes da declaração. (linha 50, arquivo "Código"). E a linha 50 é justamente a linha console.log()

Comment: Pois é. Tem que ver o que mostra `(dataRange[i][5]-dataHoje)%90`. Como vc disse, o problema pode estar aí.

Comment: [19-02-07 07:28:32:207 EST] false
[19-02-07 07:28:32:209 EST] false

Comment: Usei o Logger.log, ao invés do console.log, e ele me retornou FALSE e FALSE, o que significa que as duas condições que eu estou testando são falsas e é por isso que o código não está enviando o email. Correto? No entanto, na minha planilha, o tipoAlerta, que está na coluna P, dataRange[i][15], e o monitoramento, que está em K, dataRange[i][10], possuem, sim, os valores Trimestral e "Em Andamento", respectivamente.

Comment: Veja os valores de "tipoAlerta" e "monitoramento" antes do if para ver o que mostra, se realmente mostra o que vc quer. Qualquer divergência vai impedir que o if seja acessado.

Comment: Ao inserir Logger.log((dataRange[i][5]-dataHoje)%90) antes do primeiro IF, como sugerido, o log me exibe FALSE 250 vezes. Mas lembro que, conforme o código, quando eu faço isso, ele acaba caindo dentro do FOR.

Comment: Descobri que o problema tá na variavel var dataHoje = new Date();
Para isso, eu criei uma coluna na planilha que armazena uma formula do spreadsheet com a data de hoje, no caso, =TODAY() e substitui new Date() por ela(já atualizei o código).
Mas a questão é que eu preciso mesmo usar o New Date(), ou algo equivalente no código. O New Date() retorna o dia de hoje, então,não sei porque não deu certo.

Comment: Resolvi de uma outra forma: criei uma coluna que chamei de expire =  dataRange[i][7] no código. Nessa coluna, eu subtrai no spreadsheet a coluna F, que tem a data futura e =TODAY(), data de hoje. Quando essa diferença dá 90, o e-mail é enviado normalmente.